# NestJS: How to inject a service into a provider from the same module?

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, dependency-injection, nestjs

Is it possible to inject a service into a factory provider from the **same module**? I have a service `AppService` that I would like to use in this factory provider below.

Here is my code:

`app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
        {
            name: 'List',
            imports: [AnotherModule],
            useFactory: (anotherService: AnotherService) => {
                const schema = ListSchema;
                schema.pre('save', function() {
                    // Validate
                })
                return schema;
            },
            inject: [AnotherService],
        },
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I want to be able to do something like this:

`app.module.ts`

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeatureAsync([
        {
            name: 'List',
            imports: [AnotherModule, AppModule],
            useFactory: (anotherService: AnotherService, appService: AppService) => {
                const schema = ListSchema;
                schema.pre('save', function() {
                    // Validate
                })
                return schema;
            },
            inject: [AnotherService, AppService],
        },
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
  exports: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This does not work. Nest fails to initialize all dependencies and the application does not run.

Is it even possible to do something like this?

How can I inject a service from the same module into this factory provider? One solution would be to move that service to a different module and then inject that service. However, I would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to add a service from the current module into a module that the current module imports as a part of it's bootstrap, as that would be a major circular dependency between the two. You may be able to get around it would some interesting `forwardRef()` functions, but overall, that kind of pattern should be avoided as it brings confusion into the codebase

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was looking into `forwardRef()`, but as you pointed out, that does not seem to be suitable for what I'm trying to do. I'm better off moving the logic to a separate module and then injecting that. Thanks for your help!